# paintComponent is called twice when trying to call on other function

Tags: java, swing, paintcomponent

Trying to use the paintComponent method to draw some strings with the help of an other method called drawMyString. It seems like the drawMyString will only draw the strings once paintComponent has finished, which means if I want to draw two strings then it will first draw two empty rows.

This is the code I have been working on:

```
public class DrawStrings extends JComponent {

    private int row=0;

    public DrawStrings() throws HeadlessException {
       setPreferredSize(new Dimension(700, 400));}

    public static void main(String[] args) {
       JFrame frame = new JFrame("DrawStrings");
       frame.add(new DrawStrings());
       frame.pack();
       frame.setVisible(true);
    }

    private void drawMyString(Graphics g, String text){
        g.drawString(text, 0, row);
        row +=20;
    }

    @Override protected void paintComponent(final Graphics g) {
       g.setColor(Color.BLACK);
       g.setFont(new Font("serif", Font.PLAIN, FONT_SIZE));
       drawRow(g,"this is row number 1");
       drawRow(g,"this is row number 2");
    }
}
```

The expected output:

```
>> this is row number 1
>> this is row number 2
```

Actual output:

```
>>
>>
>> this is row number 1
>> this is row number 2
```

How come this occurs and how do I fix it, keeping the drawMyStrings function?

Comment: You should expect `paint` methods to be called multiple times, and write your logic accordingly. You could initialise your `row` variable to zero in `paintComponent` if that is your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Like khelwood said, you will need to initialize your row first and this you can do by setting it two 0 in the beginning in paintComponent.